# AnyLogic- Select Output condition

Tags: anylogic

I'm very new to AnyLogic and currently struggling to figure out one thing: I have a scenario wherein my model customers arrive at a shop and depending on how many items they purchase they will stay different amounts of times in the system.

Is there a way that the input: SelectOutput can be dependent on the condition: the number of items? Because in my case I want to have that if they buy less than x number of items they will go to delay 1 and if they buy more than x then they will go to delay 2 (as seen in the picture).

[image: selectOutput]

I already inserted the list with the number of items into my model (this was provided to me) and also inserted variables that will draw its values from the database, but I really don't know if it's the right approach or even useful.

Like I said I'm very new to AnyLogic, so if anything is unclear or my question doesn't make sense just tell me, and hopefully the attached pictures will explain the issue a bit more.

[image: variable]

[image: Overview]

Answer (score 0):

the number of items should be a variable inside your agent and the selectoutput condition should be

```
agent.numberOfItems<10
```